# Appium Issue: Could not find aapt Please set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable with the Android SDK root directory path

Tags: appium, appium-android

i have issue:

> Could not find aapt Please set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable
>   with the Android SDK root directory path.

full:

> [debug] [W3C] Encountered internal error running command: Error:
>   packageAndLaunchActivityFromManifest failed. Original error: Could not
>   find aapt Please set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable with the
>   Android SDK root directory path.

my bush_profile:

export

> JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/QA/Library/Android/sdk export
>   PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

appium-doctor:
[show that all okey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jt1m8.png)

this settings correct work for desktop appium and no issue

but for console version all time have issue

> [debug] [W3C] Encountered internal error running command: Error:
>   packageAndLaunchActivityFromManifest failed. Original error: Could not
>   find aapt Please set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable with the
>   Android SDK root directory path.

i already checked all topics but not found resolve
pls help

Comment: It will be great if you can also mention the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Aapt file will be inside the `build-tools` folder. Add the path(according to you machine) in environment variable as mentioned below.

```
D:\...\sdk\build-tools\20.0.0\
```

For more details please have a look on below link.

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/aapt2

Hope it will help.

Comment: Please accept it as valid Answer to help community. It will help others who will face same issue in future.

Answer (score 0):

First you try to look aapt at your ANDROID_HOME, if not found, aapt can find in sdk platform tools from here: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools
Then set ANDROID_HOME to that folder path.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for Mac which worked for me:

Open Appium Desktop. Go to "Appium -> Configurations" and set "ANDROID_HOME" with your path like `/Users/andrii/Library/Android/sdk`